# Baked texture is distorted - it has some weird lines

Tags: texture-baking, baking

When I try to bake my texture it comes out looking like this:
[image]

I thought at first it were my textures but it seems to be not the source of the problem. I already tried everything I could imagine that could solve the issue but unsuccessful. I would really appreciate the help!

Here is the file:
[Shelf_Bake_Test](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16EeOJxmcFZQXHy_DKyM2skbobdEqOzKa/view?usp=share_link)

Thank you very much for any help:-)

Answer (score 0):

You've set a *Max Ray Distance*, it will stop the ray before it hits the face it is supposed to bake. Bring back this value to 0 so that the ray is infinite and the bake will work fine.

Also increase the *Extrusion* value,  it will move away the start point of the ray so that you won't miss any high-poly topology that would protude out of the low-poly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @moonboots

Comment: Thank you @moonboots I tried it just now. My Max Ray Dist. was set to 0.01 before. So I tried as you commented the value of 0 which produced a similar result with the stripes. I also tried the value of 1 and it almost looked the same as the value of 0 also with the stripes. So I tried to change the Extrusion setting and omg it works just fine with Extrusion at 0.001 and Ray Dist. at 0.01. But I do not understand way.  As I understand the Extrusion setting works only with the Cage ticked? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/baking.html

Comment: No you don't need any cage for Extrusion, actually Extrusion acts like a kind of cage, it will move away the start point of the ray so that you won't miss any high-poly topology that would protude out of the low-poly

Comment: Top! Thank you very much @moonboots:-)